# 'Range' is an interface type and cannot be used as an expression

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have been trying everything and I have absolutely no idea why this is not working. I have looked at countless previous questions and answers and nothing works. I have a dialog where the user selects a number of files that can then be imported into Excel. The problem arises when setting the import range.

```
Dim files As New OpenFileDialog
files.Multiselect = True
files.InitialDirectory = My.Settings.path

If (files.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
    My.Settings.files = files.InitialDirectory
    My.Settings.Save()
    MsgBox("Files to be imported: " & files.Multiselect, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.path) Then
        MsgBox("Warning! No files were imported!", MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End If
End If  

Dim openExcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim openWorkbook As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim openWorksheet As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

openExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
openExcel.Visible = True
openExcel.UserControl = True
openWorkbook = openExcel.Workbooks.Add
openWorksheet = openWorkbook.ActiveSheet

With openWorksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=My.Settings.files, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))

End With
```

It keeps giving me the error: "BC30111 'Range' is an interface type and cannot be used as an expression"

Comment: Sounds like you need to remove the type name and construct the expression using valid elements. Just my thought...

Comment: Try with `With openExcel...` instead of `With openWorksheet`

Answer (score 1):

Your `Range` is returning a different worksheet than the QueryTable is on.

Try it like this:

```
With openWorksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=My.Settings.files, Destination:=openWorksheet.Range("$A$1"))
```

Or this:

```
With openWorksheet
    With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:=My.Settings.files, Destination:=.Range("$A$1"))
```

Comment: That seemed to help a bit but now I am getting this one:

_An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC_

Comment: Are you sure it's from the same line?  `800A03EC` is the code for Excel file access errors.  Seems like a different problem.

Comment: Yep, definitely the same line. I even added a Culture changer to make sure it is en-US but it still throws this error.  I am using Visual Studio 2015 and the Office version I use is 2007.

Comment: @james then it's trying to tell you that it cannot get the requested access to the file.

Comment: @James Best guess would be that your `.My.Settings.file` value is not a valid connection string for the `.QueryTables.Add` method.

Answer (score 0):

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837764.aspx

Try removing the $ from `Range("$A$1")`

Comment: That link has nothing about removing the "$".   Some explanation would help.

Comment: The link has this: "The destination range must be on the worksheet that contains the QueryTables object specified by expression." which is precisely your answer, +1 cheers.  The $ was more of a hunch that was causing Excel to throw an error.  It is also my preference, since I believe that is really only useful when creating equations on the spreadsheet (not VBA).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that it doesn't know where "Range" is coming from, try this:

```
With openWorksheet
    QueryTables.Add(Connection:=My.Settings.files, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
End
```

Comment: `With` only affects expressions with leading dots, like `.Range` and *not* `Range`.